# Unable to trigger event of components on map OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, mapping, react

I'm new to Openlayers, currently have a ReactJS project that used OpenLayers for displaying maps. When users are in the map component, They can click on any address (coordinate) in the map to fetch and see the corresponding data.

The fetched data can be one or many so to handle that, I decided to display the popup with paging to contain the data. However, when popup data is displayed, I'm unable to trigger the event like clicking to the next page or previous page from the paginated component.

Is any way to handle this in OpenLayers?

[image]

***EDIT***
Here is the code for `handleCreateMap` and `handleMapClick` events in Openlayers
https://jsfiddle.net/csng5z7p/1/

And here is the test paginated component with seed data

```
const PaginatedItems = ({ itemsPerPage }) => {
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(null);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    setCurrentItems(popupItems.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(popupItems.length / itemsPerPage));
  }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage]);

  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % items.length;
    setItemOffset(newOffset);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "0px", width: "500px" }}>
      {/* <Items currentItems={currentItems} /> */}
      <Items currentItems={currentItems} />
      <ReactPaginate
        nextLabel="next >"
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        marginPagesDisplayed={2}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        previousLabel="< previous"
        pageClassName="page-item"
        pageLinkClassName="page-link"
        previousClassName="page-item"
        previousLinkClassName="page-link"
        nextClassName="page-item"
        nextLinkClassName="page-link"
        breakLabel="..."
        breakClassName="page-item"
        breakLinkClassName="page-link"
        containerClassName="pagination"
        activeClassName="active"
        renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: @TomazicM Sorry, I've edited the post! The code is too long and I just want to ask is possible to trigger event on map for OpenLayers.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers which will greatly simplify what you are doing (disclaimer: I am its author)